# Which unity do the linear and angular speed have in the teleop_twist_keyboard node?

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering the unity of linear and angular speed when running the teleop_twist_keyboard node in ROS, are there m/s and rad/s? I could not find anywhere this information.

Additionally, as time dependent speeds, do they use the real time or simulated time?

Cheers,
Simone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285266/which-unity-do-the-linear-and-angular-speed-have-in-the-teleop_twist_keyboard-node?/) by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q248465 and #q212296 for related (and possibly duplicate) questions.

Summary: everything is in SI units, following [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2